# How to select DISTINCT rows without having the ORDER BY field selected

Tags: sql, mysql, distinct

So I have two tables students (PK sID) and mentors (PK pID). This query

```
SELECT s.pID
FROM students s JOIN mentors m ON s.pID = m.pID
WHERE m.tags LIKE '%a%'
ORDER BY s.sID DESC;
```

delivers this result

```
pID
-------------
9
9
3
9
3
9
9
9
10
9
3
10  etc...
```

I am trying to get a list of distinct mentor ID's with this ordering so I am looking for the SQL to produce

```
pID
-------------
9
3
10
```

If I simply insert a DISTINCT in the SELECT clause I get an unexpected result of 10, 9, 3 (wrong order). Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that you actually mean to order by 9, 3, 10. You probably have some other criteria for ordering that you aren't telling us -- a name or date associated with s.pID perhaps? Your code implies there's something magical about s.sID, what is it?

Comment: What order do you expect when ordering by s.sID, as opposed to s.pID ?

Comment: Why don't you just tell us why 9,3,10 is the "correct" order? Note that the database is not required to choose to return the first row with a particular distinct value; it might be easier for the engine to choose the last one, or one in the middle, or ...

Comment: I am ordering by the PK on the student table to get a list of the latest students added to the table (the primary key auto increments). The long result above shows the mentorID field for these students. The desired order is 9,3,10 because if you go down that list the first unique id you get is 9, the second unique id is 3 and the next unique id is 10

Comment: Could you use MIN on the student primary key id with a group by on the mentorID? I'd need to know the column name of the primary key and mentorID to give you the actual SQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT s.pID
FROM students s JOIN mentors m ON s.pID = m.pID   
WHERE m.tags LIKE '%a%'
GROUP BY s.pID
ORDER BY MAX(s.sID) DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't receive records in any predefined order if you don't use `ORDER BY` because then the DB engine decides in what order to return them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.pID
FROM students s JOIN mentors m ON s.pID = m.pID
WHERE m.tags LIKE '%a%'
GROUP BY s.pID
ORDER BY s.sID DESC;
```

I.e. GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT should preserve order.

Comment: i check it with group by it's not working according to requirement.

Comment: I've tried this before posting the question. When there are no aggregating functions in the SELECT clause GROUP BY works exactly like DISTINCT according to some expert comments on similar topics here

Answer (score 0):

After using distinct "ORDER BY s.sID DESC;" will not work so try using somwthing like following

```
SELECT distinct(s.pID) as PID
FROM students s JOIN mentors m ON s.pID = m.pID
WHERE m.tags LIKE '%a%'
ORDER BY PID;
```

This will return >> 3, 9, 10

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.pID as PID
FROM students s JOIN mentors m ON s.pID = m.pID
WHERE m.tags LIKE '%a%'
ORDER BY s.sID DESC,1;
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling some more I have this

```
SELECT s.pID, MAX(s.sID) AS newest_student
FROM students s JOIN mentors m ON s.pID = m.pID
WHERE m.tags LIKE '%a%'
GROUP BY s.pID
ORDER BY newest_student DESC;
```

which gives me the required 9,3,10 but I have one useless field returned with it.
I am hoping some-one will come with a better solution.