# order by clause question

Tags: sql-server

Can we sort on a column which is not present in the SELECT clause?   Why?

Comment: Do not SHOUT - please!  Welcome to SO, but we do not like being shouted at.  I'll fix your question that much at least, but for future reference - all caps will get complaints every time.

Comment: What Jonathan means is that do write in all caps. In internet world it is considered shouting. Been in a situation myself :)

Comment: [SO 2590621](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590621/how-to-select-distinct-rows-without-having-the-order-by-field-selected) is somewhat related.  So, too, is [SO 265628](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265628/order-by-items-must-appear-in-the-select-list-if-select-distinct-is-specified).

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the DBMS (and often the version of the DBMS - older versions being more rigid than newer versions).

These days, most DBMS do in fact allow you to sort on a column that is not listed in the select-list.  However, the earlier SQL standards certainly required the columns in the ORDER BY clause to appear in the select-list too.

The DBMS handles it by adding the non-selected column to the result set, sorting, and then projecting away (dropping) the non-selected column.

Note that using the technique means that the data order conveys information that is not available by simply looking at the data - what is called *essential* ordering.  This is not usually a very good idea (but it is popular enough that most DBMS allow you to do it).

Answer (score 3):

The ORDER BY will refer to the table(s) in the FROM clause, unless the semantics of the sort are modified by DISTINCT or GROUP BY.

This is *OK* because information from mytable1 is available:

```
SELECT col1, col3, FROM mytable1 ORDER BY col2
```

This *fails* becase col2 has no meaning after the DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col3, FROM mytable1 ORDER BY col2
```

When col1, col3 is collapsed by DISTINCT you lose values of col2. The same applies to a GROUP BY (DISTINCT is effectively a simple GROUP BY).

Answer (score 0):

When the DBMS is SQL-Server the answer is yes. But I noted that the tag was edited by Jonathan and perhaps this answer doesn't apply to your system.

Comment: I didn't change the tags (it was [skaffman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/21234/skaffman) who did) - I just turned the volume down on the question text.

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry my fault. Thanks for the note.