# How to select columns where Some Columns should not repeat

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-ce

**Read this or not:** Hey guys, its been 2 days for me searching to find a better solution to this issue. But I fail every time.

**The issue:**

I am having an issue with SQL, actually what I want to do is to select columns from a table without getting a double value or should I say I want to select the columns using `SELECT DISTINCT`. But at the same time I want to order them using `ORDER BY Time DESC` too. When I use `GROUP BY` I get errors, because using GROUP BY can work when all other columns are in some function like `COUNT(column_name) AS Column_Name` but I don't want to Sum or Count the columns. I want to get their values.

Here is the image for my Database columns. Its just a start for them. What they are? They are messages table. Where the users' messages will be stored and queried.

[image: message table..]

**What I want to get:**

What it should be like is this:

Each Message should be `GROUP BY` or simply selected as `DISTINCT` but I get some errors. I have told about those errors above. However, I can select the columns if I use this only.

```
"SELECT DISTINCT Sender, Recipient FROM Messages WHERE Sender =2 OR Recipient =2";
```

Using this do get me to some results, but I cannot order the results so I need to get the time too. And when I use `DISNTINCT Time` I get all of the 4 rows, because `Time` isn't same.

**How can you help:**

Either provide me with an example code of the above Database table, or tell me a good suggestion for how to access data from this Table so that it:

1. Gets ordered by Time
2. Sender and Recipient don't repeat.

Remaining I will get through a requery inside the block.

Thanks for your time anyways. Cheers!

Comment: Depending on your DBMS this will be more or less complicated, so please add your database system

Comment: @StuartLC did it. He tagged the question with `sql-server-ce`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, each of the repeated `Sender, Recipient` combinations can have different `Time` values, thus making the `ORDER BY` meaningless.

However, if you have a way of projecting the values of `Time` for each combination into a meaningful scalar for the combination, then instead of the `DISTINCT`, you can use `GROUP BY`, which will then allow you to `ORDER BY` a field which isn't in the `SELECT`, provided that you use an aggregate as well, i.e.

```
SELECT 
   [Sender], [Recipient]
FROM 
  [Messages] 
WHERE 
  [Sender] =2 OR [Recipient] =2
GROUP BY 
  [Sender], [Recipient]
ORDER BY 
  MIN([Time]); -- Or some other aggregate, e.g. Average etc.
```

Not my original work : See here [How to select DISTINCT rows without having the ORDER BY field selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590621/how-to-select-distinct-rows-without-having-the-order-by-field-selected#2592090)

Comment: I get this error: Expressions in the ORDER BY list cannot contain aggregate functions.

Comment: SQL CE doesn't have many features of the fuller versions of SQL :( You might need to do the `DISTINCT` in memory (e.g. LINQ) rather than in the RDBMS.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only issue. However thanks for your help and time. I think the only option left will be to hard-code it!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you may try :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  Sender, 
  Recipient,
  MIN(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Sender, Recipient) AS MinTime
FROM Messages 
  WHERE Sender =2 OR Recipient =2
ORDER BY MinTime
```

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I guess it should. Worth giving a try I would say ;-)

Comment: Nope, `OVER` is not allowed in SQL CE.